# cloud pub/sub with apache beam TypeError

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I want to check for new files in cloud storage for which I'm using cloud pub/sub. After after doing some analysis I want to save it to another cloud storage. From this cloud storage I will send files into BigQuery using another pub sub, and template provided by dataflow.

While I am running my code I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SentAnal.py", line 71, in <module>
    "Splitting_Elements_of_Text" >> beam.ParDo(Split()) |
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\gcp\pubsub.py", line 141, in __init__
    timestamp_attribute=timestamp_attribute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\gcp\pubsub.py", line 262, in __init__
    self.project, self.topic_name = parse_topic(topic)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\apache_beam\io\gcp\pubsub.py", line 209, in parse_topic
    match = re.match(TOPIC_REGEXP, full_topic)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 141, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

This is my code snippet:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import logging
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types
from datetime import datetime
import apache_beam as beam 
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from apache_beam.io.textio import ReadFromText, WriteToText

dataflow_options = ['--project=*********','--job_name=*******','--temp_location=gs://**********/temp','--setup_file=./setup.py']
dataflow_options.append('--staging_location=gs://********/stage')
dataflow_options.append('--requirements_file ./requirements.txt')
options=PipelineOptions(dataflow_options)
gcloud_options=options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)


# Dataflow runner
options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'
options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        source_date=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input_topic',help=('Input PubSub topic of the form '
        '"projects/*****/topics/*****".'))
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--output_topic',help=('Input PubSub topic of the form '
        '"projects/**********/topics/*******".'))

class Split(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self,element):
        element = element.rstrip("\n").encode('utf-8')
        text = element.split(',') 
        result = []
        for i in range(len(text)):
            dat = text[i]
            #print(dat)
            client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
            document = types.Document(content=dat,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
            sent_analysis = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)
            sentiment = sent_analysis.document_sentiment
            data = [
            (dat,sentiment.score)
            ] 
            result.append(data)
        return result

class WriteToCSV(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        return [
            "{},{}".format(
                element[0][0],
                element[0][1]
            )
        ]
user_options = options.view_as(UserOptions)

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    rows = (p
         | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=user_options.input_topic)
                .with_output_types(bytes) |
        "Splitting_Elements_of_Text" >> beam.ParDo(Split()) |
           beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=user_options.output_topic)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have read **bytes** from PubSub and are trying to use regex on a byte element. You first **need to convert** it to some kind of **string** element.

If you refer to the [streaming wordcount example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-streaming/), specifically the file [streaming_wordcount.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/streaming_wordcount.py) you can see that they decode the bytes read from PubSub to a unicode string like this:

```
messages = (p
            | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=known_args.input_subscription)
            .with_output_types(bytes))

lines = messages | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
```

And then they do any further text processing on the decoded `lines`.